# Dask.distributed only uses one core per node

Tags: python, dask, slurm, dask-distributed

I have a program where each task is a call to a C++ external program through `subprocess.Popen`. The tasks are arranged in a graph and everything is executed through the dask `get` command.

I have a single node version of this program that works just fine with `dask.threaded` and I am trying to extend this version to a distributed setting. My goal is to run it on a Slurm cluster but I have trouble deploying the workers. When I run the following:

```
screen -d -m dask-scheduler --scheduler-file scheduler.json
screen -d -m srun dask-worker --scheduler-file scheduler.json
python3 myscript.py
```

only a single core gets used on every node (out of twenty cores per node).

I did suspect some issues with the GIL but the script works just fine with `dask.threaded` so I am not quite sure what is going on and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am trying to distribute using a PBS cluster but can only launch one job (to have multiple nodes). Dask is using only cores on only one node. I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313707/dask-jobs-on-multiple-nodes-with-one-worker-run-on-one-node-only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking at the dashboard to see how many tasks Dask is running at a time on each worker:

Documentation here: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html

If you see that Dask is only running one task per worker then it's probably a problem in how you've set up your workers (you might want to look at the worker page to get a sense for what Dask thinks you've asked for)

If you see that Dask is running many tasks per worker concurrently then it's probably an issue with your function.

Comment: Didn't really solve the problem but at least I have more insight on what's going on, I'll open a new question with more details, thanks!