# Dask: Jobs on multiple nodes with one worker, run on one node only

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jupyter, dask

I am trying to process some files using a python function and would like to parallelize the task on a PBS cluster using dask. On the cluster I can only launch one job but have access to 10 nodes with 24 cores each.

So my dask PBSCluster looks like:

```
import dask
from dask_jobqueue import PBSCluster
cluster = PBSCluster(cores=240,
                     memory="1GB",
                     project='X',
                     queue='normal',
                     local_directory='$TMPDIR',
                     walltime='12:00:00',
                    resource_spec='select=10:ncpus=24:mem=1GB',
                    )
cluster.scale(1) # one worker 
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(cluster)     
client
```

After the Cluster in Dask shows 1 worker with 240 cores (not sure if that make sense). 
When I run

```
result = compute(*foo, scheduler='distributed')
```

and access the allocated nodes only one of them is actually running the computation. I am not sure if I using the right PBS configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
cluster = PBSCluster(cores=240,
                     memory="1GB",
```

The values you give to the Dask Jobqueue constructors are the values for a single job for a single node.  So here you are asking for a node with 240 cores, which probably doesn't make sense today.

If you can only launch one job then dask-jobqueue's model probably won't work for you.  I recommnd looking at [dask-mpi](https://mpi.dask.org/) as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. mpi may be the right way to do this.